# Dangling pointer in Delphi

Tags: delphi, weak-references, weak-ptr, dangling-pointer

I'm not using interfaces (so the objects has no reference counting). The objects may be referenced by many others, and i need to deal with the dangling pointers. FreeAndNil() doesn't solves the problem for multiple references. I need that when an object is destroyed all the pointers that references to it are setted to nil automatically. Alternatively it could be something like the Expired() method of std::weak_ptr in C++.

I could implement a "weak-smart pointer" to do this, but i'm not sure if it is an over-complicated implementation. Do you suggest another solution?. This is the untested possible solution that i'm thinking:

```
type
  TWeakReferenceable = class
  constructor Create();
  destructor  Destroy(); override;  //Set ReferencedObject:=nil for all the weak references in FWeakReferenceList
  private
    FWeakReferenceList: TList; //List of weak references to this object
  protected
    procedure RegisterWeakReference(const AWeakReference: TWeakReference<TWeakReferenceable>);   //Adds a weak reference 
    procedure UnregisterWeakReference(const AWeakReference: TWeakReference<TWeakReferenceable>);   //Removes a weak reference
  end;

type
  TWeakReference<TObjectType: TWeakReferenceable> = class
  constructor Create();
  destructor  Destroy(); override; //Destroys the object and calls UnregisterWeakReference(self) for the referenced object 
  private
    FObjectReference: TObjectType;
    procedure SetReference(AReferencedObject: TObjectType); //Calls UnregisterWeakReference(self) for the current reference, updates FObjectReference and calls RegisterWeakReference(self) for the referenced object  
  public
    property  ReferencedObject: TObjectType read FObjectReference write SetReference;
  end;
```

Comment: On a side note, Delphi does not require parentheses for empty parameter lists. You can define them for example `constructor Create;` Same goes with their usage.

Comment: I know, but i like to use them. I think they are useful to distinguish methods and attributes at a glance (also in their usage at calling them).
When i see:
MyRectangle.Area;
It could be a method or and attribute, but the parentheses makes that information explicit and gives me extra information on the code behavior.

Comment: First, I could never see importance of distinguishing methods from properties. And second, you can have `MyRectangle.Area` that is property backed up by method. You are clinging on to really irrelevant and highly unreliable coding practice.

Comment: Yes, but i'm pedant on it. I know it is recommended that if it is not necessary you don't write the parenthesis. I could have any problems with that rule if the usage of the parenthesis were indistinct all the time, but it is not the case. For example `area:=Rectangle.Area`, but `area` could not be a `Single` variable but a method reference like `function () of Object` declared at the top of the code (the same when passing `Rectangle.Area` as argument).

Comment: In spanish we used to distinguish words meaning by using an accent. For example: `solo` means `to be alone` and `sólo` means `only or just`. Now, it is not mandatory to use the accent, but in some cases it could cause a meaning confusion. So i decided to always use it when it means only or just.

Comment: The language would be far better if we had to use `()` with function calls because it would remove ambiguity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For mobile platforms, Delphi uses ARC (automatic reference counting) for objects, and the compiler has a `[weak]` attribute for declaring a weak pointer that gets nilled automatically when the referenced object is freed.

For desktop platforms, Delphi does not use ARC for objects.  However, `TComponent` has its own mechanism for handling "weak" references - its `FreeNotification()` method.  When a component is interested in another component's lifetime, it has to call the other component's `FreeNotification()` method.  `TComponent` maintains an internal list of interested components. When a `TComponent` object is freed, it calls the `Notication()` method of those interested components so they can nil their references to the component being freed.

The code you showed is not using `TComponent`, though.  So you would have to create your own registration/notification system to nil your references to freed objects.

Comment: I'll mark this as the accepted answer, because of mentioning the absence of weak pointers for desktop platform target, and propose the usage of a registration/notification system similar as it is implemented on TComponent class.